# Como seleccionar un elemento html hermano con jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo este codigo, mi idea es que me muestre una lista desplegable. Si yo hago click en cualquier elemento `li` deberia mostrarse el `div` que está inmediatamente debajo (se imprimen unos 6 li con sus respectivos div)

```
<ul>
            <?php
            foreach ($sucursales as $s) {
                $id = $s->ID;
                $title = $s->post_title;
                $desde              = CFS()->get('desde', $id);
                $hasta              = CFS()->get('hasta', $id);
                $desde_tarde        = CFS()->get('desde_tarde', $id);
                $hasta_tarde        = CFS()->get('hasta_tarde', $id);
                $desde_sabado       = CFS()->get('desde_sabado', $id);
                $hasta_sabado       = CFS()->get('hasta_sabado', $id);
                $telefono           = CFS()->get('telefono', $id);
                $whatsapp           = CFS()->get('whatsapp', $id);
                $numeromostrar      = CFS()->get('numeromostrar_loop', $id);
                $email              = CFS()->get('email', $id);
            ?>
                <li class="sucursal-individual" data-id="<?php echo $id;?>" data-open="false" data-title="<?php echo $title; ?>" data-desde="<?php echo $desde; ?>" data-hasta="<?php echo $hasta; ?>" data-hasta-tarde="<?php echo $desde_tarde; ?>" data-desde-tarde="<?php echo $hasta_tarde; ?>" data-desde-sabado="<?php echo $desde_sabado; ?>" data-hasta-sabado="<?php echo $hasta_sabado; ?>" data-tel="<?php echo $telefono; ?>" data-wp="<?php echo $whatsapp; ?>" data-nummostrar="<?php echo $numeromostrar; ?>" data-email="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                    <?php
                    echo $title;
                    ?>
                </li>
                <div class="contenido-sucursal-individual hidden" data-id="<?php echo $id;?>">
                    <?php echo $title; ?>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
```

Y este es mi codigo jQuery

```
 $(".sucursal-individual").on('click', function() {
    let id = $(this).data('id');
    if ($(this).data('open') == 'false') {
        $(this).attr('data-open', 'true')
        $(this).data('open', 'true')
        $(this).parent().children('div').data('id',id).removeClass('hidden');
        
    } else {
        $(this).attr('data-open', 'false')
        $(this).data('open', 'false')
        $(this).parent().children('div').data('id',id).addClass('hidden');
    }
})
```

Hace casi lo que espero, pero al clickear en un elemento `li` despliega todos los `div` en lugar de su `div` hijo unicamente. Al ocultarlo pasa lo mismo. Creo que el error ocurre en

```
        $(this).parent().children('div').data('id',id).removeClass('hidden');
```

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo usando:

- [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

> Obtiene el hermano inmediatamente siguiente de cada elemento en el conjunto de elementos coincidentes.

- [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-state)

> Agrega o elimina una o más clases de cada elemento en el conjunto de elementos coincidentes, según la presencia de la clase o el valor del argumento de estado.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$(".sucursal-individual").on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('hidden');
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="sucursal-individual">
    Titulo 1
  </li>
  <div class="contenido-sucursal-individual hidden">
    Mensaje 1
  </div>
  <li class="sucursal-individual">
    Titulo 2
  </li>
  <div class="contenido-sucursal-individual hidden">
    Mensaje 2
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! No conocia esa funcion!